# Kids clubhouse game?

Tags: identify-this-game

Do you remember the game we played growing up where you would try to find a red ball, roller skates, ball glove, and teddy bear? There was a clubhouse I think as well. It’s definitely a children’s game. Maybe it had dice as It was a board game.Everyone plays as kids and if you find everything you first you win.

Comment: Other information that might help.  roughly what year did you play it?  Was it game you played going up in 90's, 50s?  This will help narrow it down for people.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are thinking of Clue Jr.: The Case of the Hidden Toys, published in 1996 by Hasbro and Parker Brothers.

[Here's a link to it on Board Game Geek.](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5591/clue-jr-case-hidden-toys) You can look through the pictures and see if it looks familiar, but I'm pretty sure this is it.